# Why does metal make sound when it is hit?

Tags: material-science

When we hit a metal it makes a sharp sound. I wanted to know why and the problem is I can't even guess the answer.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Tell us more about what you already know. For example, what do you already know about sound?

Comment: What you say is generally true, but not all metals respond in the same way, and some depending on the temperature they are at. For example a bell made of lead at room temperature makes more of a 'thud' sound than anything sharp. But just cool it to liquid nitrogen temperatures and you can make it resonate like brass.

Answer (score 1):

The atoms in the metal will start to swing to absorb the hit.. the type of reaction a material shows depends on the atomic bonds..most metals are elastic and can swing.. This swinging movement is transferred to the air around it.
As you might know swinging air is the same as a soundwave. This soundwave reaches your ear and you hear a sound.
The metal hits the air and it moves, as well as a ball does when you kick it.

Answer (score 0):

The compression pulse which is produced when the hammer hits the metal bounces backwards and forwards within the metal. Most of the pulse (sound wave) is reflected within the metal rather than transmitted outside the metal into the air because the speed of sound in a metal is much bigger than the speed of sound in air. Some of the sound does escape each time the pulse hits a metal surface and so you get a succession of pulses which you interpret as a "note".  The shape and size of the metal and where the hammer hits the metal determines the "note" produced.  A triangle and cymbals which are used as instruments in an orchestra are examples of such specially designed pieces of metal.